# How to display html window without addressbar and statusbar on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can any body help me out how to display html page without addressbar and statusbar on the page.

Here is the code I have but still showing addressbar ans statusbar.

```
 window.open(link, "HelpTopics", "height=600,width=900,resizable=1,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,scrollbars=1,status=0");
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: address bar is part of the browser, not your html page, unless i'm mis-reading the question. and i don't really know what you mean by status bar. could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern browsers will not let you remove the statusbar and addressbar, due to security concerns.